# The code is not returning me the latest file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

Although I have files in the directory, the code is not returning anything, can anyone help me?

```
from pathlib import Path

date_creation = lambda f: f.stat().st_ctime

directory = Path('directory')
files = directory.glob('*.py')
sorted_files = sorted(files, key = date_creation, reverse = True)

for f in sorted_files:
    print(f)
```

Comment: The sorting is irrelevant, and we have no way to verify that you do, indeed, have any files in a directory named `directory` in your current working directory.

Comment: When I test this with `"."` instead of `'directory'`, it works just fine.  We'll need a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: In the meantime, I suggest that you do a little more work to debug your code: stick in strategic `print` statements to display intermediate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the argument that you pass to `Path()` is being interpreted as a *relative* path, rather than as an *absolute* path.

This means that, at the time of running this code, you will be looking for a sub-directory called 'directory', within whatever happens to be the current directory.

Based on this understanding, please pass the correct argument to `Path()`. That should get you the results.

For example, on my machine, the following code that uses an absolute path works fine:

```
from pathlib import Path

date_creation = lambda f: f.stat().st_ctime

directory = Path('F:/MyParentFolder/MySubFolder')
files = directory.glob('*.py')
sorted_files = sorted(files, key = date_creation, reverse = True)

for f in sorted_files:
    print(f)
```